# Safemint using ethers js

Tags: solidity, erc-721, ethers.js, mint

My safemint of ERC721 code is something like this:

```
function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();

    {some requires}

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }
```

How will I put the same code for ethers js in a react website with which I can interact with the contract code?

I have tried something like:

```
const SmartContract = new ethers.Contract(
            address,
            abi,
            signer
          )

await SmartContract.mint(
                    to,
                    amount
                    )
```

where to: the receiver address, amount is the mint amount.

But it is not working. It is giving the error:

```
RPC Error: execution reverted: ether value is invalid
```

which is handled by the require method:

```
require((cost.mul(_mintAmount)) <= msg.value, "ether value is invalid");
```

Please let me know how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending ether, to send ether with etherjs you pass an object as the last parameter to the function call with a property value, and the value should be the amount of ether in wei, this is an example `await SmartContract.mint(to,amount,{value: cost})`

Comment: you should check the etherjs utils like parseEther to get the amount of ether

Comment: Is this 'value' chosen by me as the developer? Or the users? Also why does this value field comes into context in Etherscan and ethers js for payable function, though it does not appear when I run the same code in Solidity?

Comment: this value value in this case should be chosen by the developer, or provide a way to the user to input it, but in the end if the user want it can modify it when metamask pops up, it's more like a suggestion in this case, but the ideal will be to get the price from the smart contract and pass it to value, this value really appears in etherscan when you do it in solidity but  it appears inside internal tx, because is the smart contract who does this while executing the function code

Comment: That is really good explanation. Thank you